# A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. Google Drive Api

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

**I made an android application that reads in an MPEG file uploaded on google Drive, with Google Drive Api. The reading is done correctly, but I keep getting the following error message:**

```
A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. 
See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:179)
at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:905)
at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:897)
at bwe.a(SourceFile:227)
at cdn.createFromParcel(SourceFile:10)
at bwe.a(SourceFile:227)
at cxl.createFromParcel(SourceFile:10)
at daa.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

**The function that realizes the reading is the following:**

```
     private void readTrack() 
        {
               Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .listChildren(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(idFolder2);
        }



final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> idFolder2 = 
                     new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showToast("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }

        Metadata metadata2 = null;
        for (int i = 0; result.getMetadataBuffer().get(i) != null; i++) {
            metadata2 = result.getMetadataBuffer().get(i);
            if (metadata2.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("patologiaA")) {

                DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(
                        mGoogleApiClient, metadata2.getDriveId());
                folder.listChildren(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                        metadataResult2);
                break;

            }

        }
        result.getMetadataBuffer().close();
    }
};

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataResult2 = 
                                      new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {

        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showToast("Problem while retrieving files");
            return;
        }

        Metadata metadataSong2 = null;

        try {
            metadataSong2 = result.getMetadataBuffer().get(indice);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            indice = 0;
            metadataSong2 = result.getMetadataBuffer().get(indice);
        }

        final DriveId dId2 = metadataSong2.getDriveId();
        final String name_track2 = metadataSong2.getTitle();

        t2.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
                getClass().getClassLoader());
        t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                DriveFile drvFile2 = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(
                        mGoogleApiClient, dId2);
                ContentsResult cRslt2 = drvFile2.openContents(
                        mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                        .await(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                if (cRslt2.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                    InputStream is2 = null;
                    Contents cont2 = cRslt2.getContents();

                    is2 = cont2.getInputStream();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    int nRead2;
                    byte[] data2 = new byte[20000000];

                    try {
                        while ((nRead2 = is2.read(data2, 0, data2.length)) != -1) {
                            buffer2.write(data2, 0, nRead2);
                        }
                        buffer2.toByteArray();
                        buffer2.flush();
                        buffer2.close();
                        is2.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        showToast("read error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        handlerErrore.sendMessage(handlerErrore
                                .obtainMessage());

                    } finally {

                        drvFile2.discardContents(mGoogleApiClient, cont2);
                        cont2.close();
                        cRslt2.getContents().close();

                    }


                } else {
                    showToast("read error from Google Drive");
                    handlerErrore.sendMessage(handlerErrore.obtainMessage());
                }

            }
        });
        t2.start();

        result.getMetadataBuffer().close();
    }

};
```

**I close all streams correctly and do not use the ParcelFileDescriptor, I do not understand why this error occurs**